# Change the directory file - Android Camera

Tags: android, file, camera, save, surfaceview

I have tried lots of camera examples for android, but [this](http://androideity.com/2011/10/08/hello-camera/) (http://androideity.com/2011/10/08/hello-camera/) is the firs I get to save images and view it on the gallery. But what I want to know is how to change the folder I save the images. I think actually it saves them on `sdcard0/DCIM`.

Here is the main activity:

```
public class Foto extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

private LayoutInflater myInflater = null;
Camera myCamera;
byte[] tempdata;
boolean myPreviewRunning = false;
private SurfaceHolder mySurfaceHolder;
private SurfaceView mySurfaceView;
ImageButton takePicture;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.foto);

    mySurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
    mySurfaceHolder = mySurfaceView.getHolder();
    mySurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    mySurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View overView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.segundacapa,null);
    this.addContentView(overView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    takePicture = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button);
    takePicture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myCamera.takePicture(myShutterCallback, myPictureCallback, myJpeg);
        }
    });


}

ShutterCallback myShutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onShutter() {
    }
};

PictureCallback myPictureCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera myCamera) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
};

PictureCallback myJpeg = new PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera myCamera) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(data != null){
            tempdata = data;
            done();
        }
    }
};

void done(){
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(tempdata, 0, tempdata.length);
    String url = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bm, null, null);
    bm.recycle();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    if(url != null){
        bundle.putString("url",url);
        Intent mIntent = new Intent();
        mIntent.putExtras(bundle);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, mIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Picture saved on" + url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Picture can not be saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    finish();
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
        if(myPreviewRunning){
            myCamera.stopPreview();
            myPreviewRunning = false;
        }
        Camera.Parameters p = myCamera.getParameters();
        p.setPreviewSize(width,height);

        myCamera.setParameters(p);
        myCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        myCamera.startPreview();
        myPreviewRunning = true;
    }catch(Exception e){}
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        myCamera = Camera.open();
    }

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    myCamera.stopPreview();
    myPreviewRunning = false;
    myCamera.release();
    myCamera = null;
    }       
}
```

There is also an XML layout with a `SurfaceView` (called `foto.xml`) and another called `segundacapa.xml`with a button.

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using **Images.Media** to store the image on disk (which uses default location), you can use another flavour of [insertImage()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html#insertImage%28android.content.ContentResolver,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), which takes *your* file path. You should write the file before. You don't need to convert the `onPictureTaken()->data` to `Bitmap`; you simply write the `byte[]` to a Jpeg file.

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("saved.jpg", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(data);
fos.close();
```

You can choose the file name as you wish; you can save the file with other parameters (see more about [Context.openFileOutput()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29). You can open the wile on **/sdcard** if you wish, e.g.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/saved.jpg");
```

Note that you need to request permission to write to the SD Card; check that the following line appears in **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```